# jquery clone element and append it after making changes to the original

Tags: jquery, clone

This is sort of a hypothetical question -- what I'm actually doing is not changing the color of an element -- I've been trying to figure out what is happening when I clone an element and then try to append that element later -- What I thought would happen was essentially a copy/paste -- but it's not working exactly that way--

I have an element .foo

I to make a clone of that element that I can use later

```
var $clone = $('.foo').clone();
```

I then do some stuff to the original element

```
$('.foo').css({'color', 'red'});
```

Then for whatever reason I need to destroy the original .foo and replace it with the clone:

```
$('.foo').replaceWith($clone);
```

Then I want to make changes to the new element:

```
$('.foo').css({'color', 'red'});
```

But this doesn't work?

Comment: after i replace the element with the clone any functions i attempt to perform on the new element don't work -- as in the changes are just not made

Comment: see my answer below. Your problem has nothing to do with the fact that you are replacing the element with a clone. This demonstrates that: http://jsfiddle.net/hptmW/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because your `.css()` syntax is wrong. When passing an object to that method, as you're doing, you must use colons to separate the property and value, like always in JSON:

```
$('.foo').css({'color':'red'});
```

To use a comma, remove the curly braces:

```
$('.foo').css('color', 'red');
```